# Bizzare Listbox Populating Issue; Listbox will not populate

Tags: vba, listbox, automation, userform

I have an odd issue.  Here is the background:  I'm automating excel from another application.  I have created a userform which I have named "WorkbookSelection" and on that form I've placed a Listbox control, which I've named "WorkbookList" and a command button which I've named "SelectionComplete."

Before the form is displayed I've already determined that excel is open, and the purpose of the listbox is to display the open workbooks in excel so the user can select one to import data from and export new data to.

Here is the code I'm attempting to use to populate the listbox:

```
Private Sub WorkbookSelection_Initialize()

Dim ExcelAp                 As Excel.Application
Dim FedExWkbk               As Excel.Workbook
Dim OpenedWorkbooks         As Excel.Workbooks
Dim i                       As Integer

Set ExcelAp = Excel.Application
Set OpenedWorkbooks = ExcelAp.Workbooks

For Each FedExWkbk In OpenedWorkbooks
    WorkbookList.AddItem FedExWkbk.Name
Next FedExWkbk

End Sub
```

I've also tried

```
Private Sub WorkbookSelection_Activate()
```

and

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```

No luck though.  If anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a solution here.  After steping through the sub I noticed it wasn't cycling through the open workbooks, so there was some issue where it wasn't grabbing the right instance of excel, but still wasn't creating it's own.  As such, I revised one line to late binding:

```
Set ExcelAp = Excel.Application
```

to

```
Set ExcelAp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

And lo and behold it works.  Just thought I'd leave this here for anyone in the future who may search out an answer to this situation.